# wordpress 3.5 doesn't work with load script anymore

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I used a plugin that uses this code:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load=utils,editor"></script>
```

in wordpress 3.5 it doesn’t work.
I was looking for a solution all over but I guess it's a new problem.

I tried looking at the wordpress 3.5 truble shooting but found nothing
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list?replies=4

Comment: What exactly is being output by `get_bloginfo`?

Comment: part of the post editor, the textarea and some categories to choose from

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. What is the output of `echo get_bloginfo('wpurl');`?